# Iptables Add DNAT rules to forward request on an IP:port to a container port

Tags: kubernetes, iptables

I have a kubernetes cluster which has 2 interfaces:
eth0: 10.10.10.100 (internal)
eth1: 20.20.20.100 (External)

There are few pods running in the cluster with flannel networking.
POD1: 172.16.54.4 (nginx service)

I want to access 20.20.20.100:80 from another host which is connected to the above k8s cluster, so that I can reach the nginx POD.

I had enabled ip forwarding and also added DNAT rules as follows:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.16.54.4:80
```

After this when I try to do a curl on 20.20.20.100, I get

```
Failed to connect to 10.10.65.161 port 80: Connection refused
```

How do I get this working?

Comment: Please read https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/networking/ and https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/ to learn about networking and services in k8s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 20.20.20.100 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.16.54.4:80`

But I don't recommend that you manage the iptables by yourself, it's painful to maintain the rules...

You can use the `hostPort` in the k8s. You can use kubenet as network plugin, since cni plugin does not support `hostPort`.

Answer (score 0):

why not use `nodeport` type? I think it is a better way to access service by hostIP. Please try `iptables -nvL -t nat` and show me the detail.